# android app crash on start

Tags: android, crash

Hello there i have developed a weather android app to read the xml file and display them on the screen, however when i run the app it crash here is the logcat :

```
03-26 11:07:27.454    2300-2300/synctc.me.stormy D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-26 11:07:27.455    2300-2300/synctc.me.stormy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: synctc.me.stormy, PID: 2300
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{synctc.me.stormy/synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity$$ViewInjector.inject(MainActivity$$ViewInjector.java:20)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity$$ViewInjector.inject(MainActivity$$ViewInjector.java:8)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:317)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:232)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: Please add the code of MainActivity and its layout if you need help other than what Signare did by pointing out the source of the error in the stack trace.

Comment: Please post your code and layout.

Comment: Don't post your layout, you need to check your code, you inject RelativeLayout with id of TextView

Comment: thanks alot i just fixed it and works perfectly !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double Click on this Line in your Logcat you will be directed to MainActivity Where you may have cast RelativeLayout to Textview.

**at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to main activity.
2. Check onCreateView() methode.
3. You are parsing relative layout by text view, Means you convert relative layouts id into textview.

Comment: if ans is right then plz mark as right for other also

Answer (score 0):

Find a line like (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something); either you are passing wrong id or your casting is wrong!